# Add variable in webview

Tags: android, webview, sharedpreferences

I want to add my variable to the webview. For example, I don't want : http:// example.com but, I want myvariable. 
My code is :

```
public class manager extends Activity{
EditText editText;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.manager);
        WebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
     // Instanciation du WebView...
        WebView wvSite = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);

        //...on active JavaScript...
        WebSettings webSettings = wvSite.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        //...et on charge la page
        wvSite.loadUrl("http://example.com");
        loadSavedPreferences();
 }
 private void loadSavedPreferences() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        String name = sharedPreferences.getString("storedName", "YourName");

        editText.setText(name);
    }

}
```

And I want to replace mysite.com by the variable name. 
Is it possible? and How?

Edit :

```
public class manager extends Activity{
EditText editText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.manager);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);

 // Instanciation du WebView...
    WebView wvSite = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);

    //...on active JavaScript...
    WebSettings webSettings = wvSite.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    //...et on charge la page
    wvSite.loadUrl(editText.getText().toString());
    loadSavedPreferences();
 }
 private void loadSavedPreferences() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    String name = sharedPreferences.getString("storedName", "YourName");

    editText.setText(name);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. First **find** your EditText (in onCreate), then you can use it.
Like:

```
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
```

Or you will get a NullPointerException.

Then somewhere (in the click listener of a button, for instance):

```
wvSite.loadUrl(editText.getText().toString());
```

---

In other words:

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.manager);

```
    // Add this line
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);

    WebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    // ...

    // skip this line
    //wvSite.loadUrl("http://example.com");
```

When you wanto to load the page:

```
    String someURL = "http://www.google.com";
    wvSite.loadUrl(someURL);
```

Mind that **there must be some valid URL in your EditText**, in order for your WebView to load anything

Comment: I can do that only when I load the Activity ?

Comment: It would be better, in order to be sure it is properly set to an object when you will use it. As you do with: `WebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);`

Comment: It is unclear what you tell me, can you show me please ?

Comment: I have edited my first post, can you say me if the code is correct ?

Comment: Yes. But make sure that there's a valid address in your EditText **before** it runs. Or it will show an empty page.

Comment: Nice, and if I want add /mypage.php , how to add that to my webview (it's a concatenation no ? )

Comment: `editText.setText(editText.getText.toString + "/mypage.php");` followed by `wvSite.loadUrl(editText.getText().toString());`